# Is there a way to know the type of dogecoin wallet through the receiver address?

Tags: dogecoin

I am confused right now! I mistakenly withdrew my dogecoins to an old wallet that I have no memory of. So I want to know if there is a way one can guess a wallet type through the receiver address.

This is my receiver address:
`D6zUZ42K8bo7qwbHXsMEerjuEYbdqvFAHK`

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Addresses are indistinguishable, and there is no way to determine which wallet generated any address, since the process is wallet agnostic.